# C# event hookup works in in handler's object's constructor only

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I am trying to hook up `interface.MessageReceived` to `logger.LogReceivedMessage`. If I add
    interface.MessageReceived += LogReceivedMessage;
in `logger`'s constructor, `LogReceivedMessage` is called as expected.

However, if I move the hookup to some other place in `logger`, `LogReceivedMessage` is never called.

All other hookups to `interface.MessageReceived` use `+=` and not `=`, so that's not the problem.

I used the Watch window and "Make Object ID" option in Visual Studio to verify that the code has the same instance of `interface` both places. It does. However, `interface.MessageReceived` has a different object in the constructor than the other places in the code. In fact, it seems to change every time something is hooked up to it. I'm not sure if that is expected or not.

Does anyone have any ideas why I can only hook up the handler in the constructor?

**Edit:**
I've gotten it working, but I'm not sure why it works. Original code in the `interface` class:

```
public event Action<Message> MessageReceived;
busClient.MessageReceived += MessageReceived
```

I changed it to:

```
public event Action<Message> intermediateMessageReceived;
public event Action<Message> MessageReceived;
busClient.MessageReceived += intermediateMessageReceived;

public void intermediateMessageReceived(Message m)
{
   MessageReceived(m);
}
```

Without posting all the code to the entire project, does anyone have any idea why this behaves differently?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I don't think that anyone can answer this, in this form

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Hmm.. could it be that you have an inherited MessageReceived that you're hiding with a private/protected one of your own, i.e. not applying the override keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share what I've learned about events in C# related to this issue. We didn't understand how events worked and that caused our problem.

When you subscribe event B to event A, calling event A will only call what was subscribed to event B at the time of event B to A subscription. If the subscribers to B change, that change will not be reflected when event A is called.

The following code demonstrates:

```
namespace EventDemonstrator
{
   class Program
   {
      class BottomLayer
      {
         public event System.Action<string> Event;
        public void callEvent() { Event("bottom"); }
      }
      class MiddleLayer
      {
         public void HookUpEvent(BottomLayer bl) { bl.Event += this.Event; }
         public event System.Action<string> Event;
      }
      class TopLayer
      {
         public void TopLayerHandler(string s)
         {
            System.Console.Write(string.Format(" {0} top\n", s));
         }
      }

      static void HookBottomToMiddle_ThenMiddleToTop_ThenCallBottom(BottomLayer bottom, MiddleLayer middle, TopLayer top)
      {
         middle.HookUpEvent(bottom);
         middle.Event += top.TopLayerHandler;
         try {bottom.callEvent(); }
         catch (System.NullReferenceException) { System.Console.Write("HookBottomToMiddle_ThenMiddleToTop_ThenCallBottom: Event was null\n"); }
      }

      static void HookMiddleToTop_ThenBottomToMiddle_ThenCallBottom(BottomLayer bottom, MiddleLayer middle, TopLayer top)
      {
         middle.Event += top.TopLayerHandler;
         middle.HookUpEvent(bottom);
         System.Console.Write("HookMiddleToTop_ThenBottomToMiddle_ThenCallBottom:");
         bottom.callEvent();
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         HookBottomToMiddle_ThenMiddleToTop_ThenCallBottom(new BottomLayer(), new MiddleLayer(), new TopLayer());
         HookMiddleToTop_ThenBottomToMiddle_ThenCallBottom(new BottomLayer(), new MiddleLayer(), new TopLayer());
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
HookBottomToMiddle_ThenMiddleToTop_ThenCallBottom: Event was null
HookMiddleToTop_ThenBottomToMiddle_ThenCallBottom: bottom top
```